# How in C# to send array/collection in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net, sqlcommand

It`s working fine and insert in my first table values

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Author (LastName, FirstName, MiddleName,BirthDate)VALUES(@LastName, @FirstName, @MiddleName,@BirthDate);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", _connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", LastNameTextBox.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstNameTextBox.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", MiddleNameTextBox.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthDate", BirthDateTextBox.Text);
string authoriD = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Here I have problem and can't solve it

```
SqlCommand commandB = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Book(AuthorID,Book,Genre,Pages)VALUES(@AuthorID,@Book,@Genre,@Pages)", _connection);
commandB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AuthorID", authoriD);

for (int i = 0; i < AddBooks.BookTextBoxValue.Count; i++)
{
    commandB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Book", AddBooks.BookTextBoxValue[i]);
}

foreach (string itemgenre in AddBooks.GenreTextBoxValue)
{
    commandB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Genre", itemgenre);
}

foreach (string itempages in AddBooks.PagesTextBoxValue)
{
    commandB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pages", itempages);
}

commandB.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: You should do an insert for every loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every author, he/she writes books with genre, etc... so you only should have one for loop.
Your code flow should be something like this:

```
for(...)
{
//insert into Book (author, book, genre, pages)
}
```

Your **Book author field** is a foreign key to **Author** table. An author can have many written books, so your **Book** table must have multiple entry for a single author. Your **Book** table should have contents like this (in order of: author, book, genre, pages):

- You, MyNewBook, Genre1, 10
- You, MyOldBook, Genre2, 20,
- You, MyNotSoNewBook, Genre1, 100
- You, MyVeryNiceBook, Genre1, 1000

Comment: i have my usercontrol that have 3 textbox,BookAdd.ascx.cs i got  public  StringCollection for each textbox.

Comment: but problem that i can`t understan how can i need create SqlCommand , because i don`t know how much books will be , 1 ,2 3 ... etc . When someone add new author,he/she can add one or more book , and when press button "save" i need to save my new author take his id , and his books.How can i add permanent count of books without hardcode.

Comment: Hi @nickshp, I rarely visit stackoverflow this year. But let me answer your inquiry even if you aready found some way. To solve the problem, you need to keep track on the number of books added per author. You can do this by getting the row/line count property of the form control and use that value within your for loop's condition.